# cURL not returning after receiving 404 response

Tags: http, curl, http-status-code-404

I have a webserver I have made in C (school project)

It seems to handle 200 response codes fine. However when i try to use cURL to test 404, it doesn't return/exit.

For example:

```
$ curl localhost:5555/q.txt
...
```

If I use verbose.

```
$ curl -v localhost:5555/q.txt
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5555 (#0)
> GET /q.txt HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: localhost:5555
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
< Date: Fri, 14 Aug 2015 11:16:32 AEST
< Connection: close
< Server: myserver/jnd
<
```

The full message I am sending back is:

```
HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\nDate: Fri, 14 Aug 2015 11:18:10 AEST\r\nConnection: close\r\nServer: myserver/jnd\r\n\r\n
```

Am I missing something here? A new-line or other formatting?

Answer (score 0):

It seems cURL will just wait until you close the connection.

So if I just `close(fd)` afterwards, it works.